# bash doesn't find "./file" altough file is in current directory

Tags: linux, bash

This tells me that there is a file called `arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc` in the current directory:

```
manuel@manuel-VirtualBox:~/linux-cortexm-1.12.4/tools/arm-2010q1/bin$ ls -l
total 16808
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  547548 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-addr2line
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  572276 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  990268 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-as
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  207668 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-c++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  547324 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-c++filt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  206548 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  547152 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-elf2flt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel   76172 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-flthdr
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  207668 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-g++
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  205140 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  205140 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc-4.4.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel   26760 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-gcov
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel 3051052 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-gdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel 3051052 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-gdbtui
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  607360 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-gprof
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel   28628 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-ld
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  958404 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-ld.real
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  556092 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-nm
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  705268 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-objcopy
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  836092 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-objdump
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  572308 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  308072 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-readelf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  551680 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-size
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  346704 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-sprite
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel  547516 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-strings
-rwxr-xr-x 2 manuel manuel  705268 Apr 14  2010 arm-uclinuxeabi-strip
```

However, when I'm trying to execute it, bash tells me that that file doesn't exist:

```
manuel@manuel-VirtualBox:~/linux-cortexm-1.12.4/tools/arm-2010q1/bin$ ./arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc --version
bash: ./arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: No such file or directory
manuel@manuel-VirtualBox:~/linux-cortexm-1.12.4/tools/arm-2010q1/bin$
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? I have no clue.

---

### Edit: Some more command outputs

1

```
manuel@manuel-VirtualBox:~/linux-cortexm-1.12.4/tools/arm-2010q1/bin$ uname -a
Linux manuel-VirtualBox 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2

```
manuel@manuel-VirtualBox:~/linux-cortexm-1.12.4/tools/arm-2010q1/bin$ file ./arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc
./arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped
```

3

```
manuel@manuel-VirtualBox:~/linux-cortexm-1.12.4/tools/arm-2010q1/bin$ ldd ./arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc
not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: Does the bottom [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350835/i-am-trying-this-command-make-stm32f429-discovery) help?

Comment: What does `file arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc` report?

Comment: Edit your question, adding to it the outputs of `uname -a` and `file ./arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc` and `ldd ./arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc`, and people will soon realize what the answer is.  ☺

Comment: @Alex: Unfortunately not. :-(

Comment: @JdeBP: Okay, so I'm trying to run an 32bit exectuable in an 64bit OS. I tried to fix it with `apt-get install ia32libs`, but it just told me: `E: Unable to locate package ia32libs`. I'm running Xubuntu by the way.

Comment: Psst!  Answerers!  Who wants to be the first to nick [someone else's answer](https://system2014.hackpad.com/ep/pad/static/hwzwPSu1zqY)? ☺  (Feel free to answer your own question if you like, Multisync.)

Comment: JdeBP's answer contains a hyperlink that looks very promising.  In case that hyperlinked page ever goes down, but someone sees this page, the answer involved: sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6 ; then cd to a stm32f429-linux-builder and run make.  I'd feel guilty posting an answer and getting points for an accepted answer.  Not sure why @JdeBP doesn't just do that...  Get credit for fine work...